# Find the number of solutions and the minimum value

Tags: trigonometry

> Consider the following expression,
> $$L=\frac{\operatorname{cos}^6(\beta)+\operatorname{cos}^6(\alpha)-\operatorname{cos}^6(\beta)\operatorname{cos}^2(\alpha)-\operatorname{cos}^6(\alpha)\operatorname{cos}^2(\beta)}{\operatorname{cos}^4(\beta)\operatorname{cos}^4(\alpha)-\operatorname{cos}^4(\beta)\operatorname{cos}^6(\alpha)-\operatorname{cos}^4(\alpha)\operatorname{cos}^6(\beta)+\operatorname{cos}^6(\beta)\operatorname{cos}^6(\alpha)}$$
> where $\alpha,\beta\ne\frac{n\pi}{2}$, $n\in\mathbb{I}$

Then find the number of solution of $\operatorname{sin}(\theta)=L$ and the minimum value of $\left[\frac{L}{2}+1\right]$ where $[.]$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I can see that the expression is symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Also by applying $AM
\ge GM$ many times I proved $($though I'm not sure$)$ that the expression $L$ is always positive or $0$.

I'm stuck here as it seems that the arithmetic and geometric mean inequality is not adequate here. Maybe we have to use some special inequality that I don't know of. And for the second part, I have no idea.

Thanks.

Comment: What is $\theta$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici any arbitrary constant....i think the question is asking whether the value of $L$ can lie between $[-1,1]$ i.e. the range of sine function

Comment: Simplify $L$ first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Simplifying, the numerator is
$$\cos ^6(\alpha ) \sin ^2(\beta )+\sin ^2(\alpha ) \cos ^6(\beta )$$ and the denominator
$$\sin ^2(\alpha ) \cos ^4(\alpha ) \sin ^2(\beta ) \cos ^4(\beta )$$ So
$$L=\sec ^4(\alpha ) \cot ^2(\beta )+\cot ^2(\alpha ) \sec ^4(\beta )$$ Since you noticed the complete symmetry, assumr that the minimum of $L$ is attained when $\beta=\alpha$. This gives an enormous simplification and the result is obvious.